# adhoc virtual fields fat-free-framework

Tags: fat-free-framework

Hi i'm using fat free framework  ,how can i get the value of the virtual filds below '#adhoc' :

"subset" =>
 array:2 [

```
0 => Mapper {#36 ▶}
1 => Mapper {#39 ▼
  #db: SQL {#8 ▶}
  #engine: "mysql"
  #source: "groupe_client"
  #table: "`groupe_client`"
  #_id: null
  #fields: array:10 [▼
    "id_groupe_client" => array:9 [▶]
    "nom" => array:8 [▶]
    "reference" => array:8 [▶]
    "nbr_occupant" => array:8 [▶]
    "date_debut" => array:8 [▶]
    "date_fin" => array:8 [▶]
    "id_administrateur" => array:8 [▶]
    "date_heure_last_update" => array:8 [▶]
    "etat" => array:8 [▶]
    "remarque" => array:8 [▶]
  ]
  #adhoc: array:2 [▼
    "administrateur" => array:2 [▶]
    "client" => array:2 [▶]
  ]
```

**EDIT**  sorry , but i need to access to the fileds in my View ?

Comment: `$mapper->get('administrateur')` should be sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are using virtual fields?

virtual fields are setted like:

> $model->virtualfields = "select name from category";
>
> $model->load();

With this way you can use the field in the Views and Controller in the same way